# Converting a view from MKMapKit to a region

Tags: ios, uiview, mkmapview, mapkit

I am displaying an `MKMapView` with another custom view overlaid on top (the 'radar' seen below). The radar is simply a static view that always stays centered and doesn't resize - it's not a map annotation. The idea is that a user can scroll and zoom the map until the radar covers a region they are interested in.

[image]

What's the best way to get the `MKCoordinateRegion` covered by the radar? I've tried `convert:toRegionFromView:` but I'm not seeing the results I would expect:

```
print("map region: \(mainView.map.region)") 
// region: MKCoordinateRegion(center: __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.132839999999987, longitude: -95.785579999999968), span: __C.MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 74.933954323122975, longitudeDelta: 61.276015749875469))

let radarRegion = mainView.map.convert(mainView.radar.frame, toRegionFrom: mainView.map)
print("radar region: \(radarRegion)")
// radar region: MKCoordinateRegion(center: __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 32.559875544717606, longitude: -95.760911716686806), span: __C.MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 21.752004541359227, longitudeDelta: 25.901697478812096))
```

I would expect the `radarRegion` to have the same center coordinate, and a span roughly half, of those of `map.region`. Neither are true.

Here's a [small project](http://benpackard.org/SO/MapRegionTest.zip) that replicates my setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Apple documentation, `convert:toRegionFrom:` method:

> Converts a rectangle in the specified view’s coordinate system to a
>   map region.
>
> Parameters
>
> rect 
>   The rectangle you want to convert.
>
> view The view that serves as the reference coordinate system for the
>   rect parameter.

So you really need to specify the view for which you provide the coordinates as the second parameter, not the map view :)

So, I believe if you pass in the frame for the radar as the first parameter, you should pass the radar view's parent as the second parameter and that should (theoretically) work.

Basically, if `view` is the parent view of which `map` (the `MKMapView` instance) and `radar` (the radar view) are children, I tried the following code:

```
let frame = radar.frame
let radarRegion = map.convert(frame, toRegionFrom:view)
map.setRegion(radarRegion, animated:true)
```

Before the above code was executed, this is what the screen looked like:

[image]

And after the above code runs:

[image]

The basic region *is* correct though there is a little bit of shifting up.

If this is not what you were expecting with regards to the region selected by the radar view, could you please explain what I might be missing?

Comment: Thanks @Fahim, I gave that a shot but I'm not seeing much improvement.  As for the hierarchy, `mainView` is a `UIView` containing both the `mapView` and the `radar`. I attempted `mainView.map.convert(mainView.radar.frame, toRegionFrom: mainView.map)` and `mainView.map.convert(mainView.radar.frame, toRegionFrom: mainView.radar)` but still not seeing what I'd expect.

Comment: But `mainView.map` would not be the right one for the second parameter, would it? I believe it should be `mainView` since the radar.frame would be in `mainView` coordinates, so shouldn't that be `mainView.map.convert(mainView.radar.frame, toRegionFrom: mainView)`?

Comment: Alas, also not working. Do you think it would be any use to add the results of each of the combinations I've tried?

Comment: Not sure that would help :( But if you are able to share the project with me (I don't know if you can or not), I can certainly take a look to see if I can figure out what is going on ...

Comment: Added an example project to the question.

Comment: Thanks, Ben :) Will take a look as soon as I can. I have to go out now but will definitely get back to you on this since I like solving this kind of puzzle :)

Comment: @BenPackard Setting the region to the mainView appears to work as far as I can tell :) I will update the main answer with more details and screenshots explaining what I did and how I verified that the new region was correct ...

Comment: Unfortunately the demo project doesn't place the radar in the center of the view - I've now fixed that in the link. On the new version, tap the 'log' button.  Why would the logged center coordinate of the map be different from that of the map?

Comment: It shouldn't matter if it is centered or not for your purposes as long as the new region matches the old region covered by the radar right? What I'm saying is that the region you get is the right one. Not sure about the center coordinates though. Will have to take a look at the new project to see what is going on.

Comment: You're right. The radar region is accurate. And the difference is quite small. Thanks!

Comment: @BenPackard I believe the difference in region is actually due to the radar region being a square and the device screen being rectangular :) If you try with a radar region which has the same aspect ratio as the device screen, you'll probably get a much closer fit :)